# How can I get the selected item from dropdownlist in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.td_company_name, ViewBag.Listcompany as IEnumerable, new { @class = "form-control" }) }
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected value is bound to the ViewModel property you define in the expression you pass as first parameter to `DropDownListFor`. In the example you have given this would be `td_company_name`. To get the selected item, retrieve it from the available options using the selected value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostAction(td_company model) {
    var selectedValue = model.td_company_name;
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> availableOptions = Listcompany();
    SelectListItem selectedItem = availableOptions.Single(opt => opt.Value == selectedValue);
     // ...
}
```

Comment: i wante to get item not value